# How to trigger event receiver on library when adding items to library through silverlight control?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, event-receivers, silverlight

I created an event receiver which triggers when an item added to the library.And it is working fine when i am adding items at library level(By clicking upload in ribbon controller of library).But the problem is I had a silver light control on a page and i am uploading item to library through that page. Here while uploading my event receiver code was not working .   My code to prevent upload is
properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithRedirectURL;
The redirection not happening in silverlight control,but it preventing the upload by showing one error message in silverlight pop-up.Any ideas on how to use the event receiver to trigger when using silverlight control (or) how to customize that silverlight pop-up message through javascript?

Any help is much appreciated!